# Have maven test run binary on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Is it possible to have Java kick off a program on another thread on Jenkins?

I have a Java application that I use for testing and have on a Jenkins server, so that Jenkins can run the tests on a schedule / watch svn. I'm having an issue with it because my app needs to run a separate binary at the same time. This, in itself, is trivial, I simply run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec('binary')` and it works on my machine, without Jenkins. However, as soon as I run it on Jenkins it won't run, but doesn't throw an exception either. I checked the permissions for the binary, and it's executable, so I'm at a loss of what's going on. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you execute that binary manually on jenkins host ? does it have GUI need that jenkins os doesn't have ? does it have permission issue ?

Comment: is it a path issue? test with /the/full/path - might want to look at file permissions as well.